# Movie about making a movie about zombies when real zombies show up

Tags: story-identification, movie, zombie

It's a zombie movie, but they are also making a zombie movie. Then real zombies come out.

At one point, a guy takes a girl in a trailer and has sex with her. He starts to bleed when he pees. And it's not contracted

Comment: [One Cut of the Dead](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4wBImbHqhFk)? Warning: Gory trailer.

Comment: This question is far too terse. What else do you remember about the film?

Comment: @Gonziboyzma - What Valorum is asking is, when did you see it? Was it in English or subtitiled? Was it in color? On TV  or in the theaters? What style (shaky cam, etc) was it? Did it appear to be high or low budget? Any details can help.

Comment: I think I saw it on Netflix it was American

Answer (score 1):

While it's hard to tell on so little information, a good candidate for this would be Romero's *[Diary of the Dead](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0848557/)* (2007). This is about a group of students making a horror film in the woods at the beginning of a zombie outbreak.

The wiki blurb starts outs with

> Film footage from a news crew shows a story about an immigrant man killing his wife and son before committing suicide. The son and wife turn into zombies and kill several medical personnel and police officers, but leave one medic and a reporter bitten before being killed. The narrator, Debra, explains that most of the footage, which was recorded by the cameraman, was never broadcast.
>
> A group of young film studies students from the University of Pittsburgh are in the woods making a horror film along with their faculty adviser, Andrew Maxwell, when they hear news of an apparent mass-rioting and mass murder. Two of the students, Ridley and Francine, decide to leave the group, while the project director Jason goes to visit his girlfriend Debra (the narrator).

There is more, but it basically spoilers the entire plot.

Comment: Is there a scene where a guy pees blood?

Comment: Yes there is scene where he pees blood